# Display own records in grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

Im new to asp and i need u guys to guide me pls? Okay, lets just straight to the point. How to display current user who logged in to the system their own data? Like my system is about tracking expenses spent by user monthly. So, once user entered the expenses, prices for that particular month, it will be stored in db of course. But the tricky part here is when the user log in again, they should be able to view back their own records. So, basically i have a drop down menu which is used for month, Jan-Dec, grid view which to view all the particular user's records, view button (when user choose month,they click on the button and the grid view will show the expenses for that particular month) and thats all. So, if you guys have any idea, solution, pls tell me how. I would be appreciated if you could gimme the step by step to do that. Thank you.

```
|username|Month|Expense1|price 1| Expense2|Price2|....//this is the eg of my db structure
```

P/s: i dont know how to use **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name**. If you could guide me by gimme the steps, that would be great! Thank you again.

Comment: hope you are going through this answer below. Incase if it is helping you to solve your problem please mark it as answer or post reply so that we can update the answer or provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You must be having a Login form to login and view monthly expense and make new entries.

Now you can follow the below steps and make all your application working.

Assuming you have created the database to store new users information with there passwords and expenses table storing data related to the expense with respect to particular user after login.

**Steps**

1. once the user is logged in to your application. You can store the
   `User ID` in `Session`.
2. This session can help you to take are which user is logged in or there are no users logged in currently to your application
3. since you have the database filled with all the details related to
   expense. After login check if you have any user id in your session
   or your session is null or not.
4. if you find any User ID session just pass this as a `SqlParameter` to your `store Procedure` and fetch all the records of this User id.
5. If you find any records bind your results to grid view. Otherwise display no records found and give a provision to Add new Expense Detail.
6. If you are using `MemberShip API` for Maintaining User Account and Login then you can user the  `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` get the User ID from this name using `MemberShip` class in `System.Web.Security` namespace.

Hope the above steps are clear and you follow the functionality properly, to solve your problem.